# Visual Studio Extension build failing with Error VSSDK1077: Unable to locate the extensions directory. "Value cannot be null

Tags: msbuild, vsix

I have configured a TFS(2017) build pipeline to compile a VS extension with debug mode for a specific requirement which require .pdb files. 
The build solution task fails for "debug" configuration with below error, however same pipeline works for the release configuration.
I have tried the approach mentioned in the following discussion as well, howewer it doesn't resolve my issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd220999-5761-475a-bf86-98dff6b35218/unable-to-compile-vsix-project-that-is-a-part-of-my-solution-using-amd64-msbuild-from-vs2015?forum=msbuild

Appreciate if someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Following is the build configuration used for the Build Solution task:
[image]

Following build variables are used to configure build parameters.
[image]

Build Error message:

> packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.1.192\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets
>   (633, 5)
>   packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.1.192\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(633,5):
>   Error VSSDK1077: Unable to locate the extensions directory. "Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: path1". Process 'msbuild.exe' exited
>   with code '1'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Update your Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools NuGet package to latest version 15.9.3032, just in case it is a problem already solved.
2. Release configurations can also generate PDB files (Project properties, Build tab, Advanced...button, Output > Debugging information). So, if the Release configuration works for you, you can keep using it while also generating a pdb file with full debug information.
3. The error is happening when, once compiled correctly, the generated VSIX output file is going to be deployed to the folder for extensions of the experimental VS instance, which is a required step to debug the VSIX file. A possible explanation of the different behavior for Debug/Release configurations is that maybe your .csproj specifies <DeployExtension>False</DeployExtension> for the Release configuration. By default, if not set, that property is set to true in the Microsoft.VsSDK.targets file:

   <DeployExtension Condition="'$(DeployExtension)' == ''">true</DeployExtension>

Since likely you don't need to deploy the VSIX to the VS experimental instance when building on a build server (because you are not going to debug it), you can set that property to False to skip the deployment. This can be done with a 3rd build configuration (ex: "DebugBuildServer"), for which you specify DeployExtension to False in the .csproj file, or sticking to two build configurations but passing the /p:DeployExtension=false in the MSBuild arguments of the Visual Studio Build task of your build pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Adding "/p:DeployExtension=false" resolved the error for me. However, MsBuild doesn't emit the .pdb for the extensibility project even with debug mode on. I tried it by opening the solution is VS IDE and it also doesn't emit the pdb. Can you help me on this as well?

Comment: Check the Project properties, Build tab, Advanced...button, Output > Debugging information

Comment: The debugging information was set to full, so I had a look at the xml of .csproj and identified that CopyOutputSymbolsToOutputDirectory = false. I changed it to true and compiled to see that pdb is copied in to the bin folder. Thanks for the support on this.

Comment: I also noticed these configurations<DeployExtension>True</DeployExtension <CreateVsixContainer>True</CreateVsixContainer>. I assume turning these off will remove the requirement of adding "/p:DeployExtension=false" build parameter as well.

Comment: It seems that your .csproj had some property values changed from the defaults after creation. You will want to create the Vsix container even on the build server since it's an essential part of the build process (the ultimate output of it). So keep the property CreateVsixContainer to True.

Comment: What you don't want is to deploy the extension on the build server. But if you set the DeployExtension property to False in the Debug configuration of the .csproj file, it won't be deployed either on the local computer to debug in the VS experimental instance. While there must be MSBuild properties to tell if you are building inside Visual Studio or not , or inside a build server or local computer, passing /p:DeployExtension=false as parameter in the build pipeline is explicit and much more clear.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero, I have the same problem and `DeployExtension=false` is work for me, but how I can debug extension now? If we need not build only. All actions on local machine.

Comment: @UserName, that error should not happen on local machine with VS properly installed. Extensions must deploy correctly. Repair or reinstall VS and update the VS SDK NuGet package.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero, I tried, but without positive results. Full uninstall, then install again, repair, etc.